# Auto Increment in SQL INSERT Query?

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-ce, increment

I am connected to a SQL Server Compact Edition Database. One of the tables involved has 3 columns - CompanyID, CompanyName and CompanyNotes. I have created a form in Visual Basic to add a new company to the database, and of course I don't want the user to have to manually put in the company ID.

In the dataset.xsd I have created an INSERT SQL query that simply inserts a new row with the CompanyID, CompanyName and CompanyNotes. I have set the CompanyID to auto-increment. However, when I tried inserting the name and notes it didn't like it because I set the ID field to be mandatory. How will I insert the new company data into a new row with a new ID?

The very basic code I currently use for adding a new company:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Me.CompanyTableAdapter1.AddCompany(??????????, txtCompanyName.Text, txtCompanyNotes.Text)
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

What should I put instead of the '?????', or should I be doing something completely different?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you also post the code that you are using to insert the record into the database? I guess it's in the body of the `AddCompany` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply omit the ID field in your SQL query.

```
INSERT INTO company (CompanyName, CompanyNotes) VALUES (?, ?)
```

Then your method can be simplified by removing the ID parameter:

```
Me.CompanyTableAdapter1.AddCompany(txtCompanyName.Text, txtCompanyNotes.Text)
```

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for the suggestion. About your request for the insert code, I simply added the query by right-clicking the 'company' table in my dataset.xsd design view, clicking Add->Query and then using the wizard to add the SQL query:

"SELECT [CompanyID], [CompanyName], [CompanyNotes] FROM [Company]"

Look at this screenshot for what I am describing: http://img1.uploadscreenshot.com/images/orig/10/28916570561-orig.jpg

How do you now should I change my code, given this new information?

Comment: @IceQubed: I think this tutorial tells you how: http://www.shiningstar.net/aspnet_articles/DataSet/DataSetProject7.aspx. Read the bit starting from "Creating our Insert Query with Parameters"

Comment: That is a great tutorial, thanks. However, for some reason the part where I can edit the identity etc is greyed out. Any ideas why this would be? http://img1.uploadscreenshot.com/images/orig/10/28917173646-orig.jpg

Comment: @IceQubed: Is the CompanyID column a varchar instead of an integer? Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

This should be done at the database level with an auto-incrementing identity specification:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN ColumnName IDENTITY (/*seed*/1, /*increment*/1)
```

Once the identity column is in place, you can omit the identity column during inserts, as it will be assigned automatically on insert.